# Выполнение транзакции SQL

Tags: sql

Что произойдет в случае, если во время выполнения транзакции отключится электричество?

Comment: транзакция будет откачена при старте сервера (если это конечно ваша СУБД нормально поддерживает транзакции)

Answer (score 2):

В общем понимании *[транзация](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F))*, как говорит Вики, это:

> минимальная логически осмысленная операция, которая имеет смысл и может быть совершена только полностью.

В [информатике транзакция](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)) это:

> группа последовательных операций с базой данных, которая представляет собой логическую единицу работы с данными. Транзакция может быть выполнена либо целиком и успешно, соблюдая целостность данных и независимо от параллельно идущих других транзакций, либо не выполнена вообще, и тогда она не должна произвести никакого эффекта.

Из чего можно сделать вывод, что, если Ваша **СУБД** настроена должным образом, то незавершенная операция (считай незавершенная *транзакция*) не пройдет (не будет выполнена операция *update/insert/delete*). То есть в БД не будет выполнено действий.

Как заметил участник *Mike* - если "упадет" сервер БД, то при его старте транзакция будет "откачена" обратно. Если упадет клиент, не завершив операцию - БД затронута не будет.

Comment: что значит - *Если упадет клиент, не завершив операцию - СУБД затронута не будет*?

Comment: @Anatol это значит, что если клиент послал запрос и на середине выполнения запроса "у него выключается эл-ство", то запрос выполнен не будет

Comment: определитесь с терминологией тогда - сначала *клиент послал запрос и на середине выполнения запроса*, потом *запрос выполнен не будет*; плюс *СУБД затронута не будет* - субд как может быть затронута?

Comment: Кстати, все еще интереснее с отключением как клиента так и сервера. Если клиент успел дать commit и сервер успел зафиксировать у себя факт того, что commit был дан - он завершит транзакцию. Хотя этот нюанс - завершить/откатить при аварии после commit может зависеть от СУБД.

Comment: @Anatol imho вы к словам придираетесь, Ep1demic разумеется имеет в ввиду, что начавшийся выполнятся и прерванный запрос в итоге не выполнит никаких изменений в БД, даже если он начал эти изменения делать, т.е. состояние БД будет приведено к тому, которое было на начало транзакции

Comment: @Mike imho ответчик не понимает разницу между бд и субд, а так-то разумеется всё понятно мне и вам. Автору вопроса тоже?

Comment: @Anatol а Вы реально сомневаетесь?

Comment: @Ep1demic судя по ответу и ответу на первый комментарий - есть все основания считать так. Не считаете нужным редактировать ответ?

Comment: @Anatol у Вас достаточно репутации для редактирования, предложите свой вариант

Comment: @Ep1demic заманчиво, но нет. Может кто другой придёт и поправит, а может и так сойдёт

Comment: Раз вы уже затронули клиента - прийдется тогда вам чиркануть строчку про сервер.

Comment: @nick_n_a не совсем понимаю, что Вы имеете в виду, там есть про сервер строчка